# Converting string to array and display vertically

Tags: javascript, arrays, string

My assignment requires I ask the user to input a string such as "This is a beautiful day" then the string is displayed vertically in reverse, like this..

- day
- beautiful
- a
- is
- This

The issue I'm having is that instead of the string being delimited by the smaces, it's delimiting every single character and displaying the string like this...

- d
- a
- y
- l
- u
- f

etc...

I've tried messing with the spaces in between the quotes in the variables as well as the "sentence.split( " " ) but no luck.

```html
  <! DOCTYPE>
  <html>
<head>
<meta charset = "utf-8"> 
  <script>

  function allStrings() 
  {
    var sentence = window.prompt( "Enter a sentence:" );
    var splitString  = sentence.split( " " );
    var flip = "";

    for( i=splitString.length-1; i>=0; i-- )
    {
      flip = flip + " " + splitString[i];
    }
      for( i=0; i<flip.length; i++ )
    {
      document.write(flip[i]);
      document.write("<br>");
    }
  }

  allStrings();
  </script>
    </head>
  </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to turn 'flip' into an array before iterating.

```
for( i=splitString.length-1; i>=0; i-- )
    {
      flip = flip + " " + splitString[i];
    }

      // at this point flip is a string, so the next for loop will iterate through each character
      // convert to an array
  flip = flip.split(" ");

  for( i=0; i<flip.length; i++ )
    {
      document.write(flip[i]);
      document.write("<br>");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I made a few minor changes to your code.

```
<! DOCTYPE>
  <html>
<head>
<meta charset = "utf-8"> 
  <script>

  function allStrings() 
  {
    var sentence = window.prompt( "Enter a sentence:" );
    var splitString  = sentence.split( " " ).reverse();
 
      for( i=0; i<splitString.length; i++ )
    {
      document.write(splitString[i]);
      document.write("<br>");
    }
  }

  allStrings();
  </script>
    </head>
  </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the `flip` variable and the second `loop`. you can just print out the value from the `splitString` array.

```
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <script>

        function allStrings() {
            var sentence = window.prompt("Enter a sentence:");
            var splitString = sentence.split(" ");

            document.write("<ul>");

            for (i = splitString.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
                document.write("<li>" + splitString[i] + "</li>");
            }

            document.write("</ul>");
        }

        allStrings();
    </script>
</head>

</html>
```

Comment: Thank you this is much simpler and more straight forward than what I was attempting to do.

Comment: If you find this answer helpful please accept it.

Answer (score 0):

The solution can be much simpler:

```js
const fn = () => {
  const sentence = window.prompt( "Enter a sentence:" );
  return sentence.split(' ').reverse().join('<br>');
}
document.getElementById('content').innerHTML = fn();
```

```html
<div id="content"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you this is super easy. We haven't used the reverse method yet in my class so I think I should use methods discussed in the chapter that this assignment pertains to. We are using "Internet and World Wide Web How to Program Dietel 5th edition". It's outdated but it's what we are using.